# Fulfillment via cloud function (inline editor) not working when using Enviroments on dialogflow

Tags: dialogflow-es, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I'm trying to deploy my Dialogflow Agent with Genesys but when I link it to a specific environment the webhook via cloud function stops working! It only works when I link it with the Draft env. Does someone have the same issue?  [env configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bbFsj.png)